# Sentencia if no reconoce el operador ||

Tags: php, if, operador

Tengo una problema tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
$model = new Crud();
$model->select = "a.idAplicacion, a.idPaciente,  p.nombres, p.apellidos,  a.peso";

$model->from = "aplicacion a JOIN paciente p ON a.idPaciente = p.idPaciente JOIN unidad u on p.Unidad = u.Unidad";

if ($_SESSION['Unidad']!=4):
    $model->condicion ="u.Unidad = ".$_SESSION['Unidad'];
endif;

$model->orderby = "a.idAplicacion DESC";
$filas = $model->verTodos();
```

El funcionamiento del código es el siguiente: hace una consulta ala base de datos si la Unidad es diferente de 4 entra y muestra sólo los pacientes de esa Unidad de ser lo contrario me muestra todos los pacientes, quiero modificar el if para que entre cuando la Unidad sea diferente de 4 y 3 entonces modificó el if pero no me funciona creo que es algo mal en la sentencia

```
if (($_SESSION['Unidad']!=4) || ($_SESSION['Unidad']!=3)):
    $model->condicion ="u.Unidad = ".$_SESSION['Unidad'];
endif;
```

Comment: Concuerdo con @t

Comment: ¿no querrás usar `&&` en vez de `||`? De lo conrario tu condicion será siempre cierta ya que un número o bien es distinto de 3 o es distinto de 4 (ya que si es el 3, es distinto de cuatro,  y si es 4 es distinto de 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador `||` significa `OR` Lógico osea, el `IF` va a entrar cuando sea:

- != 4 y != 3 (True or True = True)
- != 4 y == 3 (True or False= True)
- == 4 y != 3 (False or True = True)
- == 4 y == 3 (False or False = False) Este es el único caso en que no va a entrar

para que solo entre cuando sea `!= 4` y `!= 3` simultáneamente debes usar el operador `AND` que es `&&` en lugar de `||`.

Espero que se entienda, tu `if` debe quedar de esta manera:

```
if (($_SESSION['Unidad']!=4) && ($_SESSION['Unidad']!=3)):
    $model->condicion ="u.Unidad = ".$_SESSION['Unidad'];
endif;
```

Comment: Gracias!, estas en lo correcto, asi si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El problema aqui es que tu quieres que haga algo (if) cuando ambas condiciones se cumplan, para ello debes usar el AND (&&). Cabe mencionar que los operadores logicos funcionan asi:

- AND (&&): Si al menos una condicion es FALSE, devolvera FALSE.
- OR (||): Si al menos una condicion es TRUE, devolvera TRUE.
- NOT ( !): Invierte la condicion (Si es TRUE pasa a ser FALSE y viceversa).

Es decir que tu codigo debera ser asi:

```
 //  Si es diferente a 4      Y  Si es diferente a 3
if (($_SESSION['Unidad']!=4) && ($_SESSION['Unidad']!=3)):
    $model->condicion ="u.Unidad = ".$_SESSION['Unidad'];
endif;
```